# Interop with native libraries in linux

Tags: c#, mono, dllimport

I am writing an application in C#, which is cross platform. It uses `DllImport` for several different libraries. It is also both x32 and x64.
It seems to work right for my own compiled .dll/.so. I put the x32 shared libraries in the x32 sub-folder, and the x64 shared libraries in the x64 sub-folder.

On windows via .net framework I call `SetDllDirectory("x32" or "x64")` depending on the current 
runtime. On mono, either through windows, linux or mac, I use a `DllMap`, in RandomLibrary.dll.config. It works fine for files that are located in the x32 or x64 directories.

However, I also use `DllImport` for libraries that I didn't write, such as FreeType2. On windows, I just shove the built libraries in the two sub-folders. However on linux I would rather use the libfreetype6 library that you can install via your friendly local package manager. I can hardcode the DllMap link to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype`.so.6, but I assume that the freetype file will change depending on what distro you use.

Is there any easy way where it can just find libfreetype.so regardless of what distro I am using?

Comment: For example, in Ubuntu 10.04, libfreetype.so.6 is found in /usr/lib

Comment: I know, on my old laptop just having libfreetype.so worked fine. But when I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on this one, I got DllImport errors. I am hoping there is an easy way of getting it working for all distros.

Comment: I've already got open-source freetype bindings for .NET built up (MIT licensed), if you want to use it. It exposes the full public freetype API. From what I've tested, simply DllMapping to "libfreetype.so" works for Linux x86 and x64. Still a work in progress (mostly just need to move methods from the static FT class to their proper classes), if you want to help it's here:  https://github.com/Robmaister/SharpFont

Answer (score 3):

Using DllImport("libfreetype.so.6") for Linux should be enough, as the system should be configured to handle it correctly. Make sure you have the correct packages installed.
If it doesn't work you may have a misconfigured system: post the errors you get, the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env var value, the contents of /etc/ld.so.conf and the files in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/.
The output of

> /sbin/ldconfig -p |grep freetype

would be useful as well.

Answer (score 2):

Mono have a thing/procedure specifically for this, it is called [DllMap](http://www.mono-project.com/Config_DllMap). You can specify which unmanaged libaray gets loaded on which platform. Eg:

```xml
<configuration>
    <dllmap dll="foobar" os="linux" wordsize="64" target="linux/amd64/libfoobar.so" />
    <dllmap dll="foobar" os="linux" wordsize="32" target="linux/i386/libfoobar.so" />
</configuration>
```

I've not tried the above myself - The dllmap docs seem to hint that the target value isn't a path but I can't be sure.

Another approach would be to have a simple shellscript or batch file. On linux the shell script could easily work out the architecture by calling `arch` and set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` accordingly. I generally prefer a shell wrapper around my mono programs ( seeing `MyProgram.exe` on the console feels ugly )

Lastly you might have more *fun* if you pinvoke into [dlopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) or [LoadLibarary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to pre-load your shared libraries.

When your managed app starts you decide what architecture you are and then use `dlopen()` if on linux  or `LoadLibaray()` if on windows.

Comment: I know, I do currently use DllMap. The problem is finding the path to the .so that I am trying to find, since it differs from distro to distro. I have yet to try the other answer due to my main OS being windows.